# Bolt circle indication on angled ellipse

Tags: measurements, manufacturing-engineering

Ok so I am a machinist, not an engineer, but figured someone here might be able to provide some insight into my situation.

The part is 2.75" diameter and is on a 3.3* angle in the X axis on my mill. I have milled the surface flat at 3.3*, and now I need to indicate center to drill a bolt circle, accurately. tolerance is +-.005"

Comment: Could you edit your post with a sketch or photo?  It sounds like you're machining something that's got a $3.3^\circ$ wedge in it, and you're concerned about finding the center after indicating the edges?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no photos. I hesitate to take any, as a lot of information on the drawing is redacted, but its a flange with a pipe coming out of the end. The face of the flange has been milled at a 3.3* angle. For the sake of the explanation, and also how I'm holding my work, I have my part angled in the X axis. A flat ellipse would be no big deal, but with the thickness of the flange, it throws all kinds of angles in there.

Answer (score 1):

The center of an ellipse inscribed in a rectangle is the center of the rectangle.

Using the above property, you can randomly set two perpendicular axes by marking the middle of any line using precision parallels and the intersection of those two axis will be the center of the ellipse and the center of your bolt.

I assumed your part is a cylinder; correct me if not!